# c# Set CurrentRow value for datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a C# WinForms application. I have a DatagridView and anytime the focus comes to DataGridView I want the first record to be selected. When one form closes, I am setting the focus to the DGV. But then the selected record is not the first one but the previously selected record. So I am using the line `dgvRecords.Rows[0].Selected = true;`. So, it shows the selected record correctly. But when I get the current record from `DataSource.Current` it giving different record.

My code is below:

Setting Datasource to DGV:

```
BindingSource grpBindingSource;
grpBindingSource = new BindingSource();     
IEnumerable<Group> gList = GetAll(rectyp);
grpBindingSource.DataSource = gList;    
dgvRecords.DataSource = grpBindingSource;
```

Code to set focus:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) 
{
      dgvRecords.Focus();
      dgvRecords.Rows[0].Selected = true; //here highlighted row is first row
}
```

Fetching the record:

```
Group group = (Group)grpBindingSource.Current; // the record selected is different than the record highlighted.
```

Is there any way that I can set the Current row of the datagridview?
P.S. : I am trying this using keyboard arrow keys not mouse clicks.

Comment: SelectedRow and CurrentRow can be different. And CurrentRow is readonly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690097/currentrow-in-data-grid-giving-first-row-after-selecting-differant-row

Comment: `CurrentCell` is instead read-write and that sets the `CurrentRow`. Selected != current, you can have many *selected*, but just one *current*